# Having required (*) show up on the component itself and not the label

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm creating a webform select options component and I want to hide the label.

Because this is a required, it needs to display with the red asterisk that the field is required.

However, the asterisk is displayed against the label header and when you hide the label, it doesn't get displayed in the option itself.

[image]

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Form Placeholder](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_placeholder)? It will hide the label and add the asterisk on the select field.